# Can I find my own Google analytics audience segments I belong to?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads, privacy, ad-targeting

I want to be see my own data about what Google has grouped me as for things like affinity audience etc. I am aware I can see broad categories in 'insights' but I am interested in the more specific categories such as "Food & Dining > Frequently Dines Out > Diners by Meal > Frequently Eats Breakfast Out"